# Why nested postMessage will cause rAF fired before setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, es6-promise

Code:

```js
var mc = new MessageChannel();
var count = 1;
var t = +new Date;


console.log('start')

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise'))
requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log('animationframe'))

setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'))

mc.port1.onmessage = (...arr) => {
  console.log('ommessage')

  // this will cause the setTimeout fired **before** rAF
  if (count === 1) { mc.port2.postMessage(null); count = 2 }

  // I guess maybe because we spend too much time so the rAF be deffered? But that's not true because if I remove the upper code and use below code won't happen that
  // while(+new Date - t < 3000) {}
  // or
  // Promise.resolve().then(() => while(+new Date - t < 3000))
}

mc.port2.postMessage(null);

console.log('end')
```

If you remove the nested `postMessage`, that will work correctly. So, why does nested `poseMessage` change the event loop execution order?

By the way, increasing the delay of setTimeout will make it works correctly too, that means it's still a "time we spend" question?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do. The rAF is seen working on its own.

Comment: rAF is fired before the next tick(setTimeout), but here it fired after the next tick(setTimeout), but there is no any operation which cause drop frame, there is just a postMessage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some misunderstanding here in what `requestAnimationFrame` does, and how all these events are supposed to be happening.

So first, `requestAnimationFrame(callback)` will store `callback` in a [map of animation-callbacks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#list-of-animation-frame-callbacks). This map will get emptied and all its callbacks called at the next [**painting frame**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) (step 10).
This *painting frame* is something that the HTML specs do not clearly define when it should happen on purpose, implementors do decide when it's best to paint based on their own heuristics. For instance, Firefox will call it every 60th of a second, Chrome on the other hand will call it at the same rate than the monitor on which the page is displayed on.

So if we look at it from an external eye, we can say that `requestAnimationFrame` is just a `setTimeout(callback, time_until_next_painting_frame)`.

However, these callbacks will all get called near the end of the Event Loop.

Events on the other hand are to be processed at the beginning of the Event loop. The message event in particular is the fastest way to trigger the [queue a task](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#queue-a-task) algorithm, since it's [actually done synchronously](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/web-messaging.html#window-post-message-steps).
While timers will always fire at least two event-loop iterations later:

1. declare the timer
2. if time has passed queue a task
3. trigger the task

That's why `onmessage` should fire before timeout (though technically, a delayed timeout may fire before `onmessage`).

Now we can come to the last beast, *microtasks*, that `Promise.resolve()` creates. These are only waiting for the current execution of the **current task**. That is, the callback, event handler or inline script that did call the Promise's `resolve` method, or that did make the change that fired a MutationObserver event.

Maybe for this, a simple example is worth thousands words:

```js
const channel = new MessageChannel();
channel.port1.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(`enter message ${data} event handler`);
  Promise.resolve()
    .then( () => {
      console.log(`enter microtask ${data} event handler`);
      Promise.resolve()
        .then( () => 
          console.log(`enter sub-microtask ${data} event handler`)
        )
      // we could go into an infinite loop here
      // which would be as blocking as a while loop
      // because we never leave the current task
    } )
};

// both events should happen in the same Event-Loop iteration
channel.port2.postMessage(1);
channel.port2.postMessage(2);
```

So with all these we can come with a less high language version of your code:

```js
setPolyfills(); // so we can talk less high language

console.log('start');

queueMicroTask(() => console.log('promise'));

// it's basically random,
// though here we omit the very special case of
// *call-at-beginning-of-painting-frame*
setTimeout(() => console.log('animationframe'), Math.random() * 16.6);

setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'));

queueATask(() => {
  console.log('ommessage');
  queueATask(() => {
    console.log('onmessage');
  });
});

console.log('end');


// low-level helpers
function setPolyfills() {
  // Chrome has a native
  if( !('queueMicroTask' in window) ) {
    window.queueMicroTask = (fn) => Promise.resolve().then(fn);
  }
  window.queueATask = (fn) => {
    const channel = new MessageChannel();
    channel.port1.onmessage = e => fn();
    channel.port2.postMessage('');
  };
}
```

And given what we said before, we are in right of expecting an output like

```c
// first event-loop iteration
start       // synchronous
end         // synchronous
promise     // micro-task

// second event-loop iteration
ommessage   // beginning of second event-loop iteration
//...
```

and then `timeout`, `onmessage` and `animationframe` in a random order.

`timeout` could be fired before `onmessage` depending on when the timers are checked, it can be fired as soon as in the second iteration, or in the third one.
`onmessage` should fire in the third iteration.
`animationframe` could fire in any iteration, **from the first one** to any other until the next painting frame. Indeed, since it's actually firing at the end of the event-loop iteration, you may very well have it fire before even the message event.

Though this very rare case of being lucky enough to call it from the beginning of a painting frame should happen only once in a lot. But [Chrome has a running bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=919408#c_ts1547172496) where the first call to `requestAnimationFrame` from a non-animated document wil get called immediately, even if this frame is actually not a *painting one*... I feared you also faced this by doing your tests.

So if we now apply the workaround I proposed in this bug report, we can get more stable results in Chrome too:

```js
// workaround crbug 919408 by running an infinite rAF loop
const anim = () => requestAnimationFrame(anim);
anim();
// we thus need to wait it's warmed up
setTimeout(() => { 
  var mc = new MessageChannel();
  var count = 1;
  var t = +new Date;


  console.log('start')

  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise'))
  requestAnimationFrame(() => console.log('animationframe'))

  setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'))

  mc.port1.onmessage = (...arr) => {
    console.log('ommessage')
    if (count === 1) { mc.port2.postMessage(null); count = 2 }
  }

  mc.port2.postMessage(null);

  console.log('end')
}, 500);
```

Comment: Don't you think about your own blog with articles on the web theme? You have a huge amount of knowledge, that might be useful for the people.

Comment: By the way why do you think that timers use two event-iterations in difference to postMessages? Any evidence for it (could you provide a link to spec)? Where is the place in spec where specified that timeout for callback has gone (Is this place exist in event loop)?

Comment: No plan to own a blog, no. It doesn't require the same amount of investment as answering here and I don't have time for that. Plus you may be 5 to be interested by these stuff ;P Regarding the "timers are two event-iterations in difference to postMessage" it's not exactly what I said. TImers [*should* go](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#run-steps-after-a-timeout) ["in parallel"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel) (step 5), while `postMessage` posts the task synchronously.

Comment: So timers *should* always be late compared to postMessage. However in the facts it's not so simple. Chrome has a minimum 1ms timeout so it's a bit out of the issue. Firefox has a weird special task-queue for timers initiated before the page load, with less priority than other queues. However after this page load, they will fire 0 timeout timers with the same priority as postMessage. Making our assumption not hold.